# Hosting and database services accessible from JDBC

Tags: php, jdbc, hosting

I have a dynamic  website connected to MySQL DB on localhost and I need it to be online. I tried some hosting provider but their database is protected and not accessible from JDBC. I need hosting and database, and I'm looking for both free and paid services, do you have any solution?

Comment: the MySQL server is usually not hosted on the same server as your application. Your hosting provider will tell you which host to use and which port, as well as what the account details are. Localhost probably won't work and when you change that, you should be able to use jdbc

Comment: the hosting provider that i used specified that its database is not accessible from jdbc or external tool (he does not provide ip and port), so i'm looking for other service @FMashiro